# Routing issue in asp.net mvc 3. Displays items by category, but doesn't display all items

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, routes

I want to display items by categories. I use linq and everything works except of that I can't display all items regardless category. Probably routing issue, cause I've already asked question about linq expression that i use, and it should be fine. Anyway, here is my code:

```
public ViewResult Content(string category, int page = 1)
    { 
         var model = new StoreContentViewModel
            {
             Items = _itemsRepository.GetItems()
                             .Where(i => i.Product.Category == null || 
                                    i.Product.Category != null && i.Product.Category == category)
                             .OrderBy(i => i.ItemId)
                             .Skip((page - 1) * PageSize)
                             .Take(PageSize)
                             .Select(i => i),
             }
     }
```

And the RegisterRouts method's contents:

```
  // without categories
        routes.MapRoute(
            null,
            "Store/Content/Page{page}",
            new { controller = "Store", action = "Content", category = (string)null},
            new { page = @"\d+" });

        // with categories
        routes.MapRoute(
            null,
            "Store/Content/{category}/Page{page}",
            new { controller = "Store", action = "Content" },
            new { page = @"\d+" });

        // Default route
        routes.MapRoute(
            null,
            "{controller}/{action}",
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index"});
```

I'm confused of the order of "with and without categories" routs.

The thing is when I enter URL:

```
~/Store/Content
```

or:

```
~/Store/Content/Page1      // or Page2
```

items are not displayed.  But if I enter:

```
~/Store/Content/Man's-Shoes/Page1
```

the items that are associated with "Man's-Shoes" category are displayed.

So, do this issue has something to do with routs or mabby there is another problem??

p.s. I've been takling this issue for the last 2 days, so any help would be appropriate.

**Edited:** 
And also there is this unit test that fails. Probably it is badly written. Check it also.
In my model I have Items entity that "contains" Products and Shipping entities:

```
[TestMethod]
    public void Can_Filter_Content()
    {            
        //Arrange
        private Mock<IItemsRepository> _itemsMock = new Mock<IItemsRepository>();
        private Mock<IProductRepository> _productsMock = new Mock<IProductRepository>();
        private Mock<IShippingRepository> _shippingMock = new Mock<IShippingRepository>();

        _itemsMock.Setup(i => i.GetItems()).Returns(new[]
            {
                new Item { ItemId = 1, ProductId = 1, ShippingId = 1},
                new Item { ItemId = 2, ProductId = 2, ShippingId = 2},
                new Item { ItemId = 3, ProductId = 3, ShippingId = 3},
                new Item { ItemId = 4, ProductId = 4, ShippingId = 4}
            });
        _productsMock.Setup(p => p.GetProducts()).Returns(new[]
            {
                new Product { ProductId = 1, Category = "shoes"},
                new Product { ProductId = 2, Category = "shoes"},
                new Product { ProductId = 3, Category = "superShoes"},
                new Product { ProductId = 4, Category = "shoes"}
            });

        var controller = new StoreController(_itemsMock.Object, 
            _productsMock.Object, _shippingMock.Object) {PageSize = 2};

        // Act
        Item[] result = ((StoreContentViewModel) controller.Content(null).Model).Items.ToArray();
        ViewResult viewResult = controller.Content(null);

        // Assert
        Assert.IsTrue(result[0].ItemId == 1 && result[1].ItemId == 2);
        Assert.AreEqual(result.Length, 2);

        Assert.AreEqual("", viewResult.ViewName);
    }
```

Mabby this helps

Comment: irrelevant to your question but `i.Product.Category != null &&` part of your LINQ query is reduntant. The part after `||` will only ever execute if category is not null.

Comment: What if there is no item in the database? will it execute without the line above??

Comment: Shoudln't the `Where` clauses be added only when the `content` variable is null or empty?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should this:

```
.Where(i => i.Product.Category == null || 
      i.Product.Category != null && i.Product.Category == category)
```

Be this:

```
.Where(i => category == null || 
      i.Product.Category != null && i.Product.Category == category)
```

When category is null, the original condition says where the product category is not null, and that category matches null, which will never work.  The new condition says if the category is null, don't evaluate the condition; otherwise, match on the category ("Man's-Shoes").